# pygtk - Problems to display gtk.TextView in unity desktop

Tags: unity-game-engine, textview, pygtk

I have a problem with Unity...
My program don't show the Textview like Lubuntu or Kubuntu:

Kubuntu 14.10, my desktop: All is good
[image]

On Lubuntu 14.04(gnome), all is good: (virtualbox v.4.3.18)
[image]

**BUT** on Unity (Ubuntu 14.10, virtualbox)
The height's textview is null, even I maximize the window:
[image]

What is the problem with Unity ??

My code:

```
         # entourage détails
         cadre2 = gtk.Frame("Détails de la vidéo")
         boite_rech.add(cadre2)

         #création du tableau 2
         tableau2 = gtk.Table(rows=1, columns=1, homogeneous=True)
         cadre2.add(tableau2)

         self.fd = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
         tableau2.attach(self.fd, 0, 1, 0, 1, xpadding=10, ypadding=2)
         self.fd.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)

         self.textview = gtk.TextView()
         self.textview.set_editable(False)
         self.buffertexte = self.textview.get_buffer()
         self.textview.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_WORD)
         self.textview.set_cursor_visible(True)
         self.buffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
         self.edition = self.textview.get_editable()
         self.textview.set_justification(gtk.JUSTIFY_LEFT)

         self.iterdebut = self.buffertexte.get_end_iter()
         self.buffertexte.set_text("")

         self.fd.add(self.textview)
         self.fd.show()
         self.textview.show()
```

If you have an idea, I don't have... Thanks

I tried to delete the table but it's the same result

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found has to add a `gtk.VPaned()`to separe the textview and an invisible label:

Here is my new code:

```
     pane = gtk.VPaned()
     pane.set_position(500)

     # entourage détails
     cadre2 = gtk.Frame("Détails de la vidéo")
     pane.add1(cadre2)
     #boite_rech.add(cadre2)

     #création du tableau 2
     tableau2 = gtk.Table(rows=2, columns=1, homogeneous=False)
     #pane.add1(tableau2)
     cadre2.add(tableau2)

     #textview
     self.fd = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
     tableau2.attach(self.fd, 0, 2, 0, 1, xpadding=10, ypadding=2)
     self.fd.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
     self.textview = gtk.TextView()
     self.textview.set_editable(False)
     self.textview.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_WORD)
     self.textview.set_cursor_visible(True)
     self.textview.set_justification(gtk.JUSTIFY_LEFT)
     self.buffertexte = self.textview.get_buffer()
     self.edition = self.textview.get_editable()

     self.iterdebut = self.buffertexte.get_end_iter()
     self.buffertexte.set_text("")

     self.fd.add(self.textview)
     self.fd.show()
     self.textview.show()   

     label2 = gtk.Label("\n\n")
     pane.add2(label2)

     boite_rech.add(pane)
```

The result:
[image]

I don't know if it the best solution, but it works.